# How to get time before launching a command each time in terminal?

Tags: command-line

I would like that each time I run a command in terminal I have the time displayed in my term then the command executed.

Comment: Do you want the time to be displayed when you run the command (the moment of pressing Enter) or is it enough if the time is displayed in the prompt line, every time the previous command exits or you press Enter on an empty line?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/304270/148062

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just run

```
 PROMPT_COMMAND="date"
```

on your terminal then every time a command is ran on your terminal the current date and time will be printed out on your terminal. As suggested by@pa4080, to make it permanent, add `PROMPT_COMMAND="date"` to your ~/.bashrc file.

From man bash:

> PROMPT_COMMAND
>
> If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each primary prompt.

I think you can use the same command `PROMPT_COMMAND=` to run almost "anything" you want to run when a command is ran on the terminal.

If you use [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki), it also display time on the corner:

[image: tmux]

Comment: To make it permanent, include `PROMPT_COMMAND="date"` in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: But wouldn't that show the date/time *when the program terminated* and returned to the CLI prompt?

Comment: As stated before, this will display the time when the prompt is displayed, not the time when the command is done. If you really want to see when the time is started, you could do "date;yourcommand" (Albiet, not very convenient).

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're running Bash, you can set `PROMPT_COMMAND` to a command that is executed when the prompt is printed out. Similarly, you could run an arbitrary command by including a command substitution in the prompt:

```
$ PS1='[$(date +"%T")] \u@\h \w\$ '
[22:17:54] user@somehost /tmp$
```

But this is common enough that [Bash supports it off the shelf](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html)

> `\D{format}`
>   The format is passed to `strftime(3)` and the result is inserted into the prompt string; an empty format results in a locale-specific time representation. The braces are required.

So, similarly to the previous

```
$ PS1='[\D{%T}] \u@\h \w\$ '
```

---

But those print the time the prompt was printed. This may be quite a while before the next command is executed. To get the time the command is started, we can use the `DEBUG` trap, which runs once for each command line executed.

```
$ starttime() { date +"Command started at %T"; }
$ trap starttime DEBUG
$ ls -l /dev/null
Command started at 22:25:07
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Jul 18 21:46 /dev/null
```

The `DEBUG` trap could also use the `$BASH_COMMAND` variable which contains the command being executed, but that's probably not very useful since the command line is visible at the prompt anyway.

Answer (score 2):

use zsh terminal, this terminal can show date time run command[image]

https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes#rkj-repos
https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes#xiong-chiamiov

Answer (score 2):

1. Edit .bashrc file

   ```
   gedit ~/.bashrc
   ```
2. Find the following text:

   ```
   if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
   PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\] :\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
   ```
3. And replace with:

   ```
   if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
   PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\] [\d|\t]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
   ```
4. Restart terminal to check.

[image: Sample output in terminal]